# Can Vivisectionist retrain Throw Anything feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, alchemist, retraining

One of my players has an alchemist with vivisectionist archetype, thus loosing ability to make bombs in change of roguish sneak attack.

He tries to convince me, that Throw Anything feat gained as a bonus feat can be retrained, because the rules are silent on that matter.

The only rule I could find says that if the old feat is a bonus feat granted by a class feature, you must replace it with a feat that you could choose using that class feature.

I understand that being not bomber, doesnt mean he wont be able to throw anything else, but still the feat looks for vivisectionist rather unusable ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Unfortunately, there's no *other* feat to retrain the [Throw Anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Throw-Anything-Ex-) feat *to*

At level 1 the [vivisectionist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo---alchemist-archetypes/vivisectionist) [alchemist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist) gets the [class feature throw anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Throw-Anything-Ex-) that grants the alchemist the bonus feat [Throw Anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throw-anything-combat---final). The [Retraining](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining) rules say

> If the old feat is a bonus feat granted by a class feature, you must replace it with a feat that you could choose using that class feature.

The *only* bonus feat that's possible from the the class feature throw anything is the feat Throw Anything. There just aren't any *other* choices that can be made.

While the GM's house rules may permit otherwise, normally such a character can't retrain the feat Throw Anything when it's acquired this way.

(If the character *could* find a trainer, pay the cost, and spend the time, he could retrain the feat and still have the *same* feat. I don't know why a character would do this—a favor to an old professor? a money laundering scheme?—but that's possible.)

Comment: +1. Regarding GM's house rules - depending on how much you are concerned with game balance, it might be better to house-rule that only a specific feat (or a small selection of feats) can replace the *Throw Anything* feat, rather than allowing the player to use the retraining rules to select any feat he likes - if you are tweaking a class feature, it's better to do so in a controlled way...