# What happens when you have the same feat from different sources?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

I am playing a game where I am a monk and I choose dodge as my bonus feat. I am planning on taking magus spire defender, but at first level they also get dodge.

Without retraining, what am I suppose to do with two copies of the same feat? I cant stack them.

Comment: (As per [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68236/8610), *with* the retraining rules, a different monk feat could be picked, but a different magus feat could not.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan So as I was expecting then, it must be something that could have been done in that spot. Thanks for pointing out that question

Answer (score 7):

Without retraining, you can do nothing special with a duplicate feat; unless the feature granting the feat says otherwise (perhaps by stating "If you already have this feat from another source..."), you merely have two copies of the feat.

---

And you're right that the feats' benefits don't stack. The [PRD](https://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#feat-descriptions) has this to say on the subject:

> ...If a character has the same feat more than once, its benefits do not stack unless indicated otherwise in the description.

---

If this were 3.5, I might suggest *embrace the dark chaos* then *shun the dark chaos* spells (*Fiendish Codex II*) but even that smacks of retraining, if you were intending to avoid it.