# Can I multiclass into Planar Shepherd again to get an additional plane?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing, prestige-class

So, this is an odd little question. For this, I'd like answers to include the following, if possible:

- Rules as Written
- Rules as Intended
- Flavor-text/infamous DnD 3.5e Vagueness potential

Now on to the meat of the question. I'm in a campaign that started at level 15, and plans to take the chars deep into epic, ending with Divinity. Long-term campaign, and we've been told to plan for reaching up to lvl 40. Unusual, which is why I'm interested.

I'm playing a Druid/Planar Shepherd, and since the campaign just started am getting ready to take my 16th level.

My question is this:

Could I, ostensibly, take Planar Shepherd *again* to attune to an additional plane? Reading the rules, I know a PlanShep that changes their attuned plane has to re-start the class, but what about adding by taking the full class again?

Do note: under normal circumstances I would by no means even consider this, since PlanShep is powerful as it stands (in my opinion, the most powerful class between character lvl 14 and 16). Once we're well into epic levels, however, the power differences will shrink.

Comment: [Vaguely related.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101819/8610)

Comment: @BenBarden Please, no answers in the comments.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie that wasn't even remotely enough for an answer.  It was a "hey - you might want to look for an answer over here".  It was less of an answer than Hey I Can Chan's link immediately before it.

Comment: @BenBarden We do not support any kind of answer-like material in comments, [including short or incomplete answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533). This is because comments do not support features like proper voting and the wiki-style editing that allow us to vet, correct, and improve the content; additionally, it hijacks comments' actual purpose, and promotes one's contribution above all other answers. For more, we have [a FAQ about the exact definitions and reasons](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533). (E.g., linking to related questions is expressly in comments' purpose.)

Comment: @BenBarden Additionally, *“Pretty sure \[answer\]. Note sure where the the explicit rules are, though.”* seemed to me to be pretty safely in the answer category and didn't resemble the “might want to look over here” comment category at all, so it wasn't a difficult mod call.

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

The Player's Handbook says the following on page 59 under the header *Adding A Second Class*:

> When a character with one class gains a level, he or she may choose to increase the level of his or her current class or pick up a new class at 1st level. (A character can’t gain 1st level in the same class more than once, even if this would allow him or her to select different class features, such as a different set of domains for a cleric.)

The Dungeon Master's Guide says the following on page 176 under the header *Prestige Classes*:

> Prestige classes offer a new form of multiclassing.

Taking a Prestige Class is considered a form of multiclassing and therefore subject to its rules. And because you can't gain a class' 1st level more than once, you cannot become a Planar Shepard more than once.