# About Unchained Rogues and Standard Rogues?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue

Can Unchained Rogues use all Rogue Talents available to Standard Rogues?
If not is it ok to multiclass an Unchained Rogue with a Standard Rogue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Some rogue talents are available to unch. rogues

From [d20pfsrd](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/rogue-talents/),

> The following rogue talents from the core rogue class can be used with the unchained rogue without modification: assault leader, black market connections, canny observer, cunning trigger, deft palm, distracting attack*, fast getaway, firearm training, getaway artist, grit, iron guts, ninja trick, positioning attack, quick disguise, quick trapsmith, rope master, strong impression, strong stroke, survivalist, swift poison, underhanded, wall scramble.

Furthermore, all talents available to unchained rogue are available on [this page](https://www.aonprd.com/RogueUnchainedTalents.aspx) of the official reference website Archives of Nethys.

### You cannot multiclass rogue/unch. rogue

The [unhchained classes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/) "count as" the same class and cannot be taken at the [same time](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/101820/28326) as their base class.

Comment: 1. You can't multiclass both versions of a class. "These classes can be used alongside their original counterparts (although individual characters must use one version or the other exclusively)." 2. [Anger Management FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gw#v5748eaic9t91) 3. [Ninja Trick -> Rogue Talent](https://aonprd.com/NinjaTricks.aspx) (Note that it doesn't give you unchained Rogue Talents).

Comment: I thought that was the case, but couldn't find the text

Comment: Note: you can't multiclass Core rogue with Unchained rogue, but you can multiclass Unchained rogue with other classes (or prestige classes) that gain access to rogue talents and choose Core rogue talents that way.  Just remember that your effective rogue levels do not stack (unless otherwise specified).